# Do people from sunnier parts of the world show accelerated aging?

Tags: dermatology, symptoms, lifestyle, pathophysiology, aging

A lot of medical evidence seems to point to there being a link between sun exposure and skin aging. Would this mean that on average, a 30-year-old from Arizona would have more wrinkles and uneven skin tone than a 30-year-old from Canada?

Is there evidence to back accelerated aging, or at least skin aging, in sunnier parts of the globe?